# Is it possible to create a multiplayer 1v1 battle type Unity 2d C# game that enables the player to code in Python then compiles it for errors?

Tags: unity-game-engine, compilation, multiplayer

I am trying to create a multiplayer 1v1 battle type Unity 2d **C#** game that will show a broken **python** code which will be fixed by the players in a limited time. The game should be able to compile it and check for errors. Is this possible to incorporate such features in a unity game? I would like to ask for a head start since I am new to game development. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Arguably yes. Enjoy

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.